# automatically find and nop an instruction in IDA

Tags: ida, patching, patch-reversing

These are my first steps in IDA script, so please be kind.

I want to create some sort of script that, every time it finds the following instruction:

`MOV R1, #0x4D080`

to automatically replace it with

`NOP`

I could do it statically (hex edit), but I'm looking for a way to do it on the fly during dynamic debugging.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the processor and instruction set you working with? What do you mean by "on the fly"? Do you expect some kind of self modifying code ?

Comment: its ARM, android device. I'm using remote debugging (android_server). On the fly I mean 'in-memory', to run a script to do that while attached to the process, not before the library loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can do the following:

Assuming that you know when and where this instruction is located and where it can appear:

```
#I didn't check this code, use carefully, beware errors
#You can use idc.FindBinary instead of text search if you know 
#how your assembly instruction is encoded
import idautils
import idc


#static nopification of ARM address
def static_nopify_arm(ea):
    nop = [0xe1, 0xa0, 0x00, 0x00]  # it is a nop encoding taken from wikipedia
    for i in range(len(nop)):
        idc.PatchByte(ea + i, nop[i])


#searches assembly command by its text
#generally bad idea, but should work
#start and end means search area boundaries
def static_search_text_and_nopify(asmline, start, end):
    for h in idautils.Heads(start, end):
        disasm = idc.GetDisasm(h)
        if asmline == disasm:
            static_nopify_arm(h)


#The same with dynamic (memory during debugging)
#Dynamic nopification of ARM address
def dynamic_nopify_arm(ea):
    nop = [0xe1, 0xa0, 0x00, 0x00]  # it is a nop encoding taken from wikipedia
    for i in range(len(nop)):
        #I'm not sure that it will work, may be you should do something with memory protection
        idc.PatchDbgByte(ea + i, nop[i])


#searches assembly command by its text
#generally bad idea, but should work
#start and end means search area boundaries
#Code should be recognized by IDA as code before running the function
def dynamic_search_text_and_nopify(asmline, start, end):
    for h in idautils.Heads(start, end):
        disasm = idc.GetDisasm(h)
        if asmline == disasm:
            dynamic_nopify_arm(h)
```

Comment: A couple of notes. Be careful with byte order when you patch on ARM. On a little endian architecture, your bytes above would be backward. Second, if the area you are interested in is in a shared library loaded in the process (ie, not loaded in your IDB), IDA may not be able to generate a list of Head bytes as it has done no prior analysis.